# Advice on developing a random event engine

Tags: scripting, events, random

I am looking into creating a random event engine like the one found in the Paradox Interactive’s Europa Universalis franchise.

They use a ‘mean time to happen’ mechanic that applies various modifiers to both the human and AI players. This is all achieved via a scripted language.

What I have now is a system that imports my script of random events. Within that script is a 'mean time to happen' expressed in game turns. Each event is then queued with the game turn that it should fire +/- 10% (e.g. an event that should fire every 10 turns can happen every 9-11 turns).

When the game turn for an event comes up it checks all players to get a short list of eligible players. it then assigns a random player from the eligible list the event.

Once the event has fired it adds itself back into the queue with a new fire turn and waits to happen again.

What I am looking for here is a sanity check or if I am headed down a path that will work.

Beyond the sanity check does the community have a suggested method for scripting the events?

What I have is a simple eligibility flag with choices and the AI's chance to take each option.

example:

IF factionType == 'x'

EVENT_OPTIONS

A: AI:0.6 mod_A
B: AI:0.4 Mod_B

Comment: Welcome to the site.  A question that asks for a whole tutorial is probably too broad to be answerable here, and google is more likely to find you a guide.  If you'd like to ask about some aspect of this "mean time to happen" mechanic, you should focus on what you have already tried to do.  Have you already begun building such a system, and encountered a specific problem?  If not, that is probably the best way to begin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a simulation of your players and these events, create a parameterized function that does your option code.  Run this isolated simulation a bunch of times to see if it works for your gameplay, adjust parameters and then the function itself until it does.

**Do not make this too complex** because *simple randomness will appear complex* to the player and debugging problems with events inside a hurricane of randomness and conditional logic is a nightmare.

Does what you have actually run?  Then keep using it until it proves useful or fails to provide gameplay you want, then replace it.  Such a small piece of code, your calling this an "Engine" is giving it way too much weight.

In the end, no one can tell you whether this will work because no one here is playing your game or has any idea why you're adding randomness to the timers.  Only live testing can show you what works or not.